# ngrx - chain two store.select slices

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

In my Todo Cmp I have this code

```
this.todoListGroup$ = this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getTodos)
    .flatMap((todos: Todo[]) => {
        console.log(todos)
        this.todos = todos
        this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getLastChangedTodo);
    })
    .map(lastTodo =>{{
        console.log(lastTodo)
        doSomething(this.todos, lastTodo)
    })
```

When I subscribe to it I get one more console.log(lastTodo) each time todo changes. I figure that with flatmap and ngrx.select, I'm subscribing to a new Observable each time?

with which operator can I chain two store slices?

EDIT:

As long as the view is in the DOM, I want to stay subscribed to todoListGroup$ since it should keep updating my view.

My solution so far is to define a new slice in the reducer which returns the two desired properties. However, I'm still interested in which operator can effectively chain ngrx single property slices.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify your goal? I am thinking that you want `switchMap` if you don't want multiple inner subscriptions or `withLatestFrom` if you want both values from store but the first should be the only trigger.

Comment: is there a reason the 2 solutions I posted don't accomplish this?

Comment: sorry, haven't tried them out yet :) I was working on my own so far. But the withLatestFrom seems promising! Thanks

Comment: Rather than "define a new slice in the reducer which returns the two desired properties" you may be interested in creating projections using the `reselect` library or just raw rxjs. Here is a tutorial on creating projections with ngrx: https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510#projecting-state-for-view-with-combinelatest-and-withlatestfrom

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Would something like this work:

```
this.todoListGroup$ =
    Observable.combineLatest(
        this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getTodos), 
        this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getLastChangedTodo)
    )
    .do(([todos, lastToDo]) => console.log(todos, lastToDo));
```

The `do` would execute each time **either one** of `getTodos` or `getLastChangedTodo` is updated and would take the latest known values from each of them at the time of the update. The caveat here is the **order** of when each of those updates are fired may not always be the same. So, if you wanted more of a chained (or cascaded) update then you could do this:

```
this.todoListGroup$ =
    this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getTodos)
    .withLatestFrom(this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getLastChangedTodo))
    .do(([todos, lastToDo]) => console.log(todos, lastToDo));
```

That will execute each time `getToDos` is updated and would take the latest value from `getLastChangedTodo`. Hence the chained (or cascaded) updated idiom.

edit for rxjs 5+ syntax:

```
this.todoListGroup$ =
    combineLatest(
        this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getTodos), 
        this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getLastChangedTodo)
    )
    .pipe(tap(([todos, lastToDo]) => console.log(todos, lastToDo)));


this.todoListGroup$ =
    this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getTodos).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getLastChangedTodo)),
      tap(([todos, lastToDo]) => console.log(todos, lastToDo))
    );
```

Comment: so combineLatest creates a new Observable which emits everytime either one of the combined single Observable emits?

Comment: yes, it gives you the latest value from both each time either of them emits

Comment: Note: this approach does not use the latest version of rxjs. At time of writing, current version is 6.0

Answer (score 30):

This is an approach for RxJs v6+ using the [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) operator.

First import the operators and `Observable` function like this:

```js
import { Observable, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then you can use them like this:

```js
combineLatest([
  this.store.pipe(select('users', 'userList')),
  this.store.pipe(select('users', 'accountsList')),
]).pipe(tap(([userList, accountsList]) => console.log(userList, accountsList)))
```

Comment: CombineLatest should now be an array of store selects.

Comment: I've updated the answer to be an array of store selects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.todoListGroup$ = this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getTodos)
.flatMap((todos: Todo[]) => {
    console.log(todos)
    this.todos = todos
    this.ngrx.select(fromRoot.getLastChangedTodo);
})
.take(1)
.map(lastTodo =>{{
    console.log(lastTodo)
    doSomething(this.todos, lastTodo)
})
```

Comment: so basically i'm still subscribing to a new slice each time, but it complete after one emit?
What if I don't want to complete it?