# How to combine angular ngrx multiple select in single call

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-selectors

How I can combine both select in single function. I have tried few method eg: `combineLatest` and it's not calling [Other stackoverflow disccusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268772/ngrx-chain-two-store-select-slices). Is there any way I can both in sigle function?

```
constructor(private store: Store<fromStore.AppState>) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store
    .select("userInfo", "user")
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
    .subscribe((userInfo) => {
      console.log(userInfo);
    });

  this.store
    .select("cart")
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
    .subscribe((detail) => {
      console.log(detail);
    });
}
```

Comment: combineLatest is the better solution to combine one or more observable. But it needs all the observables to emit at least one value. You can implement it by providing `null` as `pipe(startWith(null))`

Answer (score 1):

Use selectors, then create a selector based on the user selector and cart selector.

- https://brandonroberts.dev/blog/posts/2020-12-14-maximizing-simplifying-component-views-ngrx-selectors/
- https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/solving-angular-slow-renders-with-ngrx-selectors
- https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/sharing-data-between-modules-is-peanuts

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `combineLatest`, each observable must emit at least one value. If you are not sure whether some observables emit or not, you can use `startWith` operator to guarantee that the observables emit first value. Whenever one of the observables inside `combineLatest` emits new value, it reflects the changes.

```
this.userInfo$ = this.store
    .select("userInfo", "user")
    .pipe(startWith(null),takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll));
    

  this.detail = this.store
    .select("cart")
    .pipe(startWith(null),takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll));
    

    combineLatest([this.userInfo$, this.detail$]).subscribe(([userInfo,detail])=>{...});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `combineLatest` with an `startWith`operator since each observable should emit at least one value to execute the subscribe.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  const userInfo$ = this.store.select("userInfo", "user")
                        .pipe(
                          startWith(null),
                          takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll)
                         );
    
  const cart$ = this.store.select("cart")
                    .pipe(
                      startWith(null),
                      takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll)
                     );

  combineLatest([userInfo$, cart$])
    .subscribe(([userInfo, cart])=>{ consolse.log(userInfo, cart)});        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did this way:

```
let user$: Observable<any> = null;
let detail$: Observable<any> = null;

user$ = this.store.select('userInfo', 'user');
detail$ = this.store.select('cart');

combineLatest([user$, onboardingId$])
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
            .subscribe((responses) => {.....}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i hope it work

```js
combineLatest([
            this._store.select(selectIsLoaded),
            this._store.select(selectDeptIsLoaded)])
            .pipe(
                untilDestroyed(this),
                filter(([compIsloaded, deptIsLoaded]) => compIsloaded && deptIsLoaded),
                withLatestFrom(
                    this._store.select(selectCompanies),
                    this._store.select(selectDepartments1),
                    this._store.select(selectDepartments2),
                    this._store.select(selectDepartments3),
                ),
                tap(([_, companies, departments_1, departments_2, departments_3]) => {
                    this.mapStructure({
                        companies,
                        departments_1,
                        departments_2,
                        departments_3,
                    })
                })
            ).subscribe();
```